# Group and Sort nested Objects using Java Streams

Tags: java, list, data-structures, java-stream, comparator

I have a list of `DTO` objects with the nested list field.

The aim is to *group* them by `id` field and *merge*, and then *sort* the list using Streams API.

```
class DTO {
    private Long id;
    private List<ItemDTO> items;
}

class ItemDTO {
    private Long priority;
    private Long value;
}

// input
List<DTO> dtoList = List.of(
 DTO(1, List.of(ItemDTO(1, 1), ItemDTO(7, 2))),
 DTO(2, List.of(ItemDTO(1, 1), ItemDTO(2, 2))),
 DTO(1, List.of(ItemDTO(10, 3), ItemDTO(1, 4)))
);
```

I need to *group* these nested objects with the same `id` field and *merge* all items in ***descending order*** by field `priority`.

The final result for this `dtoList` will be something like this:

```
// output 
List<DTO> resultList = [
        DTO(1, List.of(ItemDTO(10,3), ItemDTO(7,2), ItemDTO(1,1), ItemDTO(1,4)),
        DTO(2, List.of(ItemDTO(2,2), ItemDTO(1,1),
    ];
```

Can we achieve this with Streams API?

Comment: Yes, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: Could you please ping a better way solution for this? Best I got has multiple iterations :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by a simple grouping by to get a map `Map<Long,List<DTO>>` and stream over the entries of that map and map each to a new DTO. You can extract a method / function to get the `ItemDTO`s sorted:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

....


Function<List<DTO>, List<ItemDTO>> func =
        list -> list.stream()
                .map(DTO::getItems)
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ItemDTO::getPriority,Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<DTO> result = 
        dtoList.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DTO::getId))
               .entrySet().stream()
               .map(entry -> new DTO(entry.getKey(), func.apply(entry.getValue())))
               //.sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(DTO::getId)) if the resulting list need to be sorted by id
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an intermediate map by grouping the data by `id` and then transform each entry into a new `DTO` object.

For that, you can use a combination of built-in collectors [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function)) and [`flatMapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) to create an intermediate map.

In order to sort the items mapped each `id`, `flatMapping()` is being used in conjunction with `collectionAndThen()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input
    List<DTO> dtoList = List.of(
        new DTO(1L, List.of(new ItemDTO(1L, 1L), new ItemDTO(7L, 2L))),
        new DTO(2L, List.of(new ItemDTO(1L, 1L), new ItemDTO(2L, 2L))),
        new DTO(1L, List.of(new ItemDTO(10L, 3L), new ItemDTO(1L, 4L)))
    );
    
    List<DTO> result = dtoList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DTO::getId,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.flatMapping(dto -> dto.getItems().stream(), Collectors.toList()),
                (List<ItemDTO> items) -> {
                    items.sort(Comparator.comparing(ItemDTO::getPriority).reversed());
                    return items;
            })))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new DTO(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output*

```
DTO{id = 1, items = [ItemDTO{10, 3}, ItemDTO{7, 2}, ItemDTO{1, 1}, ItemDTO{1, 4}]}
DTO{id = 2, items = [ItemDTO{2, 2}, ItemDTO{1, 1}]}
```

As *@shmosel* has pointed out, `flatMapping()` is one of the boons of Java 9. You may also think of it as a reminder, maybe it's time to move to the modular system provided by Java 9 and other useful features.

The version that is fully compliant with **Java 8** will look like this:

```
List<DTO> result = dtoList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DTO::getId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.mapping(DTO::getItems, Collectors.toList()),
                (List<List<ItemDTO>> items) ->
                    items.stream().flatMap(List::stream)
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ItemDTO::getPriority).reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    )))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new DTO(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `flatMapping()` is not in Java 8. Then again, neither is `List.of()`.

Comment: Nice! But comparator on priority is missing. Possible with flatMapping ?

Comment: @Forece85 Updated, the answer. *Possible with flatMapping* - do you mean is it possible to achieve without `flatMapping()` or you mean apply sorting within `flatMapping()`?

Comment: @Forece85 Updated with the code fully complaint with Java 8 (without `flatMapping()`).

Comment: @shmosel Correct. I've missed that `flatMapping()` came with Java 9. It could be replaced with `mapping()` and `collectingAndThen()` will deal with flattening sorting. Regarding the usage of `List.of()` is handy for demo purposes and OP already has the input list, hence it doesn't seem reasonable to me replacing it `Arrays.asList()` which isn't a better option for latter version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Imo, this is the easiest way. I am presuming you had the appropriate getters defined for you classes.

- simply covert to a map keyed on the id.
- merge the appropriate lists
- and return the values and convert to an ArrayList.

```
List<DTO> results = new ArrayList<>(dtoList.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(DTO::getId, dto -> dto, (a, b) -> {
            a.getItems().addAll(b.getItems());
            return a;
        })).values());
```

Then simply sort them in place based on your requirements.  This takes no more time that doing it in the stream construct but in my opinion is less cluttered.

```
for (DTO d: results) {   
    d.getItems().sort(Comparator.comparing(ItemDTO::getPriority)
       .reversed());
}

results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints (using a simple `toString` for the two classes)

```
DTO[1, [ItemDTO[10, 3], ItemDTO[7, 2], ItemDTO[1, 1], ItemDTO[1, 4]]]
DTO[2, [ItemDTO[2, 2], ItemDTO[1, 1]]]
```

Note: `List.of` is immutable so you can't change them.  I would use `new ArrayList<>(List.of(...))` in your list construct.